# Assigning vars using sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, invoke-sqlcmd

I'm trying to make some changes to backup jobs on a server, I am wondering it's possible to create a variable and then subsequently call that in the script.

```
sqlcmd -E  -d master -Q "DECLARE @CurrentDate VARCHAR(10);
SET @CurrentDate = FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'ddMMyyyy', 'en-us') SELECT 
@CurrentDate" -b
```

I am basically wanting to create a string and use the @CurrentDate value created above. Not sure how this can be achieved, to be honest.

Comment: What are you then wanting to then do with said value of `@CurrentDate`?

Comment: I'm wanting to use @CurrentDate is an execute expression and add it to the end of a backupurl